# parsing Json using system.web.script.seriarilization or using json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

```
json ="{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1000",
         "from": {
            "name": "Anthony Waema",
            "category": "message",
            "id": "192"
         },
         "message": "this is the message",
         "updated_time": "2001-05-06T19:34:15+0000",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id": "100001692250255",
                  "name": "\u00dcnal Turanl\u0131"
               },
               {
                  "id": "100001060078996",
                  "name": "S\u00e9f\u00e2 K\u00e2ql\u00e4Nn"
               }]
              },
         {
         "id": "10150186255753553",
         "from": {
            "name": "another name",
            "category": "message",
            "id": "100001"
         },
         "message": "this is the message",
         "updated_time": "2001-04-06T19:34:15+0000",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id": "1002345",
                  "name": "\u00dcnal Turanl\u0131"
               },
               {
                  "id": "100234",
                  "name": "S\u00e9f\u00e2 K\u00e2ql\u00e4Nn"
               }]
              }
         }
]
}";

public class Allstatus
    {
        public List<sdata> data { get; set; }
        public scpaging paging { get; set; }
    }

public class sdata
    {

        public string id { get; set; }
        public sfrom from { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string updated_time {get; set;}
        public List<likesdata> likes { get; set; }
    }
   public class likesdata
    {
        public string id{ get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }
    }
public class sfrom 
{
      public string name {get; set;}
      public string category {get; set;}
      public string id {get; set;}
}

                JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                page = ser.Deserialize<allstatus>(json);
                foreach (sdata cd in page.data)
                {
                    foreach(likesdata ld in  cd.likes.data)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ld.id+"\t"+ld.name);
                    }

                }
```

problem:
I need to parse the json and retrieve likes data.
I can access "from" data but not "likes" data.. I get nullreference error when I do this. help needed here.. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit2:**

Referring https://gist.github.com/973510, its clear from the returned json, that if a particular facebook message doesnt have any likes, then the returned json doesnt contain a property called `likes`. Hence `likes` property of `sdata object` is null.  Thats just how the server returns the data.

There are two ways you can deal with this. Either do a manual check whether `likes` is null. Or initialize the likes property in the sdata constructor. And initialize the likesdata list in the likesdatacollection constructor.

Code:

```
public class sdata
{
    // other properties

    public likedatacollection likes { get; set; }

    public sdata()
    {
        likes = new likedatacollection();
    }
}

public class likedatacollection
{
    public List<likesdata> data { get; set; }

    public likedatacollection()
    {
        data = new List<likesdata>();
    }
}
```

This way, even if fb doesnt return any likes, the constructors will initialize the properties, so they will not be null. You can then check whether `likes.data.Count > 0`. If yes, then fb returned likes, else fb didnt return likes.

**Edit1:**

From the OP's comment, its clear that the json is properly formed. Meaning, the json is as retrieved from some server api. Therefore it is the `sdata` class that is the culprit. Please look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/973457) for the full solution.

The short version. For the simplest case, your c# classes need to follow the exact same structure as your json. As per the json, `data` has a property called `likes`. the `likes` object has a property called `data` which is an array of objects with properties id and name.

So your c# class `sdata` should have a property called `likes` of type `likesdatacollection`. This class should have a property `data` of type `List<likesdata>`...

Off topic, people generally seem to prefer Json.Net ... so you may want to use that. The reason I use it is because I need it to work in a .Net 2.0 code base ...

Comment: Besides using .NET 2.0, is there really a good reason for using an external library instead of the built-in JavaScriptSerializer? I'm not a big fan of taking external dependencies in an application unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Kevin, JavaScriptSerializer is inside System.Web so you won't be able to use client profiles for .NET 3.5 and above.

Comment: heelo.. So are you saying that the likes data can't be parsed like this, that the "data" attribute has to be removed for parsing to succeed?                                                                                                                          "likes": {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1002345",
            "name": "\u00dcnal Turanl\u0131"
        },
        {
            "id": "100234",
            "name": "S\u00e9f\u00e2 K\u00e2ql\u00e4Nn"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: What I am saying is that the "data" property should NOT be there in the first place. Check out https://gist.github.com/973375 ... The gist contains the actual Allstatus object and the resulting json after serializing it. There is no "data" property.

Comment: Thanks @Amith.. but I am parsing from a server api. I can't remove that "data" property.

Comment: @Amith I have ran my string through [Json lint](http://www.jsonlint.com) And the string came out valid.

Comment: In that case, the problem was with the 'sdata' class. Check out this gist https://gist.github.com/973457 ... Your classes need to exactly follow the structure of the json data and vice versa. I thought that the classes came first and assumed that the json was wrong. But the json is not changeable, so you need to fashion the classes to match the json. Hope that clears the confusion ...

Comment: @amith-george yes... your gist works for your serialized. Please check [gisted](https://gist.github.com/973510) That still brings the null reference exception.

Comment: Updated my answer. btw, did you get a notification to the effect that I edited my answer? I dont know whether I should keep commenting on my answer to let people know that I have updated the answer ...

Comment: @Amith-george I will be following the gist updates. So no need to comment.

Comment: @Amith-george I had also initialized by using contructors with actual values.. but it still brings that error..

Comment: @Amith-george. updates on the answer are not being reflected as notifications to commentors. but comments are being reflected when you leave contact addres

Comment: looking at https://gist.github.com/975175, you only added the constructor for likesdatacollection. what about the constructor for sdata? look at the updated answer ...

Comment: @Amith George Yes you are right.. There was one class which was connected to the likesdata that was not in the constructor.. Works like a charm :-D

Answer (score 1):

You should try running your JSON through a validator like [JSON Lint](http://www.jsonlint.com/). That should help you find any JSON errors.